# nginx rewrite to hide application name

Tags: tomcat, nginx

This question may be asked many times, I have been reading but still can't get what I want.

I have an application running in `172.17.1.10:8080/myapp` I would like to setup nginx reverse proxy accessing the application using   `sub.domain.com` only , hidding  "myapp" in the address bar.

my current setting is:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain.com;
        location /myapp {
                rewrite ^/myapp(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://172.17.1.10:8080;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }

}
```

but I keep viewing the Nginx index page with `sub.domain.com`, and `sub.domain.com/myapp` the tomcat index page... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't even need a rewrite on this case, this should be enough:

Updated location:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    location / { 
            proxy_pass http://172.17.1.10:8080/myapp/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
```

---

Here is an example of server simulating your backend,

Your 172.17.1.10:8080 will be my localhost:8088:

```
server {
    listen       8088;

    location /myapp {      
      # if the "login" request param = true, will simulate a redirect to a login page to proxy;
      if ($arg_login = "true" ){
          return 301 http://sub.domain.com/login;            
      }   

      #otherwise return normal content 
      return 200 "$request_uri    OK";        
    }

    #Simulated login page
    location /myapp/login {        
      echo "Login page: Provide credentials!";        
    }
```

}

So, (using a browser) if I request this: `http://sub.domain.com/api/test`

I'll get:

> /myapp/api/test    OK

whereas If I request: `http://sub.domain.com/api/test?login=true`
I'll get:

> Login page: Provide credentials!

Comment: I did that and I got infinite redirects, I use spring security and it by default redirect to /home  or  /login depdends if you have the authorization or not